# Printing content of a XML file using XML DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have a simple XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cellphones>
  <telefon>
    <model>Easy DB</model>
    <proizvodjac>Alcatel</proizvodjac>
    <cena>25</cena>
  </telefon>
  <telefon>
    <model>3310</model>
    <proizvodjac>Nokia</proizvodjac>
    <cena>30</cena>
  </telefon>
  <telefon>
    <model>GF768</model>
    <proizvodjac>Ericsson</proizvodjac>
    <cena>15</cena>
  </telefon>
  <telefon>
    <model>Skeleton</model>
    <proizvodjac>Panasonic</proizvodjac>
    <cena>45</cena>
  </telefon>
  <telefon>
    <model>Earl</model>
    <proizvodjac>Sharp</proizvodjac>
    <cena>60</cena>
  </telefon>
</cellphones>
```

I need to print the content of this file using XML DOM, and it needs to be structured like this:

```
"model: Easy DB
proizvodjac: Alcatel
cena: 25"
```

for each node inside the XML.

IT HAS TO BE DONE using XML DOM. That's the problem. I can do it the usual, simple way. But this one bothers me because I can't seem to find any solution on the internet.

This is as far as I can go, but I need to access inside nodes (child nodes) and to get node values. I also want to get rid of some weird string "#text" that comes up out of the blue.

```
<?php
    //kreira se DOMDocument objekat
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

    //u xml objekat se ucitava xml fajl
    $xmlDoc->load("poruke.xml");

    //dodeljuje se promenljivoj koreni element
    $x = $xmlDoc->documentElement;

    //prolazi se kroz petlju tako sto se ispisuje informacija o podelementima
    foreach ($x->childNodes AS $item){
        print $item->nodeName . " = " . $item->nodeValue . "<br />";
    }
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Explanation for weird #text strings**

The weird #text strings dont come out of the blue but are actual Text Nodes. When you load a formatted XML document with `DOM` any whitespace, e.g. indenting, linebreaks and node values will be part of the DOM as `DOMText` instances by default, e.g.

```
<cellphones>\n\t<telefon>\n\t\t<model>Easy DB…
E           T   E        T     E      T
```

where E is a `DOMElement` and T is a `DOMText`.

To get around that, load the document like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->load('file.xml');
```

Then your document will be structured as follows

```
<cellphones><telefon><model>Easy DB…
E           E        E      T
```

Note that individual nodes representing the value of a `DOMElement` will still be `DOMText` instances, but the nodes that control the formatting are gone. More on that later.

**Proof**

You can test this easily with this code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = TRUE; // change to FALSE to see the difference
$dom->load('file.xml');
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('telefon') as $telefon) {
    foreach($telefon->childNodes as $node) {
        printf(
            "Name: %s - Type: %s - Value: %s\n",
            $node->nodeName,
            $node->nodeType,
            urlencode($node->nodeValue)
        );
    }
}
```

This code runs through all the telefon elements in your given XML and prints out node name, type and the urlencoded node value of it's child nodes. When you preserve the whitespace, you will get something like

```
Name: #text - Type: 3 - Value: %0A++++
Name: model - Type: 1 - Value: Easy+DB
Name: #text - Type: 3 - Value: %0A++++
Name: proizvodjac - Type: 1 - Value: Alcatel
Name: #text - Type: 3 - Value: %0A++++
Name: cena - Type: 1 - Value: 25
Name: #text - Type: 3 - Value: %0A++
…
```

The reason I urlencoded the value is to show that there is in fact `DOMText` nodes containing the indenting and the linebreaks in your `DOMDocument`. `%0A` is a linebreak, while each `+` is a space.

When you compare this with your XML, you will see there is a line break after each `<telefon>` element followed by four spaces until the `<model>` element starts. Likewise, there is only a newline and two spaces between the closing `<cena>` and the opening `<telefon>`.

The given type for these nodes is 3, which - [according to the list of predefined constants](http://de.php.net/manual/en/dom.constants.php) - is `XML_TEXT_NODE`, e.g. a `DOMText` node. In lack of a proper element name, these nodes have a name of #text.

**Disregarding Whitespace**

Now, when you disable preservation of whitespace, the above will output:

```
Name: model - Type: 1 - Value: Easy+DB
Name: proizvodjac - Type: 1 - Value: Alcatel
Name: cena - Type: 1 - Value: 25
Name: model - Type: 1 - Value: 3310
…
```

As you can see, there is no more #text nodes, but only type 1 nodes, which means `XML_ELEMENT_NODE`, e.g. `DOMElement`.

**DOMElements contain DOMText nodes**

In the beginning I said, the values of `DOMElements` are `DOMText` instances too. But in the output above, they are nowhere to be seen. That's because we are accessing the [`nodeValue`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue) property, which returns the value of the `DOMText` as string. We can prove that the value is a `DOMText` easily though:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('telefon') as $telefon) {
    $node = $telefon->firstChild->firstChild; // 1st child of model
    printf(
        "Name: %s - Type: %s - Value: %s\n",
        $node->nodeName,
        $node->nodeType,
        urlencode($node->nodeValue)
    );
}
```

will output

```
Name: #text - Type: 3 - Value: Easy+DB
Name: #text - Type: 3 - Value: 3310
Name: #text - Type: 3 - Value: GF768
Name: #text - Type: 3 - Value: Skeleton
Name: #text - Type: 3 - Value: Earl
```

And this proves a `DOMElement` contains it's value as a `DOMText` and `nodeValue` is just returning the content of the `DOMText` directly.

**More on nodeValue**

In fact, `nodeValue` is smart enough to concatenate the contents of any `DOMText` children:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML('<root><p>Hello <em>World</em>!!!</p></root>');
$node = $dom->documentElement->firstChild; // p
printf(
    "Name: %s - Type: %s - Value: %s\n",
    $node->nodeName,
    $node->nodeType,
    $node->nodeValue
);
```

will output

```
Name: p - Type: 1 - Value: Hello World!!!
```

although these are really the combined values of

```
DOMText "Hello"
DOMElement em with DOMText "World"
DOMText "!!!"
```

**Printing content of a XML file using XML DOM**

To finally answer your question, look at the first test code. Everything you need is in there. And of course by now you have been given fine other answers too.

Comment: I liked other answers as they helped me quickly and easy, but this is so much more and I cannot express how much I appreciate this explanation. It is truly brilliant, Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you want something like this:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("poruke.xml");

$telefon = $dom->getElementsByTagName('telefon');

foreach ($telefon as $t) {
    print "model: " . $t->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "\n" .
          "proizvodjac: " . $t->childNodes->item(1)->nodeValue . "\n" . 
          "cena: " . $t->childNodes->item(2)->nodeValue;
}
```

This may not be exactly what you need in terms of formatting, but it should show you approximately what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution, tried and tested.

```
<?php

    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

    $xmlDoc->load("mobiles.xml");

    $x = $xmlDoc->documentElement;

    $telefons = $x->getElementsByTagName( "telefon" );

    foreach( $telefons as $telefon )
  {

      $model = $telefon->getElementsByTagName( "model" );

      $proiz = $telefon->getElementsByTagName( "proizvodjac" );

      $cena = $telefon->getElementsByTagName( "cena" );


  echo $model->item(0)->nodeName .': '. $model->item(0)->nodeValue.' <br> '.$proiz->item(0)->nodeName .':'.$proiz->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br> '.$cena->item(0)->nodeName.':'.$cena->item(0)->nodeValue.' <br><br>';

  }


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

$dom->load("poruke.xml");

// Load the DomDoc into an Xpath object, you can then query it
$xpath = new DOMXpath($xmlDoc);

// Find all telefon elements
$result = $xpath->query("//telefon");

// For each telefon item found
foreach ($result AS $item){
    // For each child node of the telefon element print the nodeName and nodeValue
    foreach($item->childNodes as $node){
        echo $node->nodeName . " = " . $node->nodeValue . " <br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Always keep XPath in mind, it is fantastic. It will keep your code clean and make finding elements in XML and HTML much easier than array mashing

Comment: While I agree XPath is fantastic (for complex queries), it should be noted that the OP gains nothing from this specific query over just using `getElementsByTagName`. Also, unless you load the XML with `preserveWhitespace = FALSE` you will also print DOMText Nodes when iterating over the child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Found a quite simple way :

```php
$xml = $domElement->ownerDocument->saveXML($domElement);
```

or if you already hold the document in a variable.

```php
$xml = $document->saveXML($domElement);
```

solution found at :
http://php.net/manual/fr/class.domelement.php