# PHP - Dom Xpath question

Tags: php, xml, dom, configuration, xpath

With this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<databases>
    <default>
        <type>mysql</type>
        <host>localhost</host>
        <table-prefix></table-prefix>
        <username>root</username>
        <password></password>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
    </default>
    <test>
        <type>mysql</type>
        <host>localhost</host>
        <table-prefix></table-prefix>
        <username>root</username>
        <password></password>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
    </test>
</databases>
```

Code:

```
public function get($xpath = '/')
    {
        $dom_object = new DOMDocument();
        $dom_object->load($this->_filename);
        $domxpath_object = new DOMXpath($dom_object);

        $domnodelist_object = $domxpath_object->query($xpath);

        return $this->XMLConfigurationToArray($domnodelist_object);
    }

private function XMLConfigurationToArray(DOMNodeList $domnodelist_object)
    {
        $configuration_array = array();

        foreach ($domnodelist_object as $element)
        {
            if ($element->hasChildNodes())
            {
                foreach ($element->childNodes as $c)
                {
                    print_r('<pre>' . $element->tagName . '</pre>');
                }
            }
        }

        return $configuration_array;
    }
```

Why it prints out databases 5 times? I call get('/databases') ...
Thank you.

Comment: you are expecting to see "databases" two times?

Comment: databases just once ... is that wrong?

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598409/printing-content-of-a-xml-file-using-xml-dom/4599724#4599724

Comment: If you only want to get `<databases>` just query / (also see my answer related to the textnodes)

Comment: Besides @Gordon precaution, this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

There are also whitespaces, which are childNodes too (textNodes)

Ignore the textNodes:

```
if($c->nodeType===1)
{
  echo('<pre>' . $c->tagName . '</pre>');
}
```

...or use also XPATH to retrieve the child(element)-nodes.

You can also ignore the whitespaces from the start(as described in the topic linked by Gordon):

```
$dom_object = new DOMDocument();
$dom_object->preserveWhiteSpace=false;
```

Comment: do you mean tabs == whitespaces? so, in xml, i cannot have whitespaces? will every whitespace be an textnode? thank you.

Comment: yes, tabs, linebreaks, spaces. You have one after `<databases>`, one after `</default>` and one after `</test>`

Comment: @thomas: No, every text node is going to be a text node. Preserving or stripping white space only text nodes is usually a matter or XML parser configuration. Check for [@Gordon's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598409/printing-content-of-a-xml-file-using-xml-dom/4599724#4599724)

Answer (score 1):

> Why it prints out databases 5 times? I
>   call get('/databases')

Because the `databases` top element has 5 children nodes: 2 elements and three (whitespace-only)text nodes, surrounding the elements.