# How do I fix this indentation issue with DOMDocument?

Tags: php, formatting, domdocument

I just started using the DOMDocument Object since I want to parse an uploaded HTML File and then use it as a template for my cms.

I'm loading HTML from a file and - for testing purpose - save it as a new html file without changing anything. The problem is: the indentation is messed up.

Here's what my HTML file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DOM Testpage</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="language" content="deutsch, de" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="pageOverlay"></div>
        <div style="height:100px;"></div>
        <div id="LoginForm">
            <div id="LoginLogo">
                Here's some Text
                <br />
                And another Text with some German Umlauts: öäü ÖÄÜ ß and so on...
                <br />
            </div>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <!-- Here be dragons. And a nice comment -->
                <input type="text" name="cms_user" value="" class="InputText " data-defaultvalue="Username" title="Please enter your username." style="margin:0px 0px 20px 0px;" />
                <input type="password" name="cms_password" value="" class="InputText " data-defaultvalue="Password" title="Please enter your password." style="margin:0px 0px 20px 0px;" />
                <input type="checkbox" name="cms_remember_login" value="1" id="cms_remember_login" />
                <label for="cms_remember_login" style="line-height:14px; margin-left:5px;">Remember Login</label>
                <!-- Another comment
                This one's even
                longer -->
                <input type="submit" name="submitLogin" value="Login" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PHP part:

```
<?php
    $lo_dom = new DOMDocument();
    $lo_dom->loadHTMLFile("test.html");
    $lo_dom->saveHTMLFile("templates/test_neu.html");
?>
```

When I open the new HTML file, the source looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>DOM Testpage</title><meta name="language" content="deutsch, de"></head><body>
        <div class="pageOverlay"></div>
        <div style="height:100px;"></div>
        <div id="LoginForm">
            <div id="LoginLogo">
                Here's some Text
                <br>
                And another Text with some German Umlauts: &ouml;&auml;&uuml; &Ouml;&Auml;&Uuml; &szlig; and so on...
                <br></div>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <!-- Here be dragons. And a nice comment -->
                <input type="text" name="cms_user" value="" class="InputText " data-defaultvalue="Username" title="Please enter your username." style="margin:0px 0px 20px 0px;"><input type="password" name="cms_password" value="" class="InputText " data-defaultvalue="Password" title="Please enter your password." style="margin:0px 0px 20px 0px;"><input type="checkbox" name="cms_remember_login" value="1" id="cms_remember_login"><label for="cms_remember_login" style="line-height:14px; margin-left:5px;">Remember Login</label>
                <!-- Another comment
                This one's even
                longer -->
                <input type="submit" name="submitLogin" value="Login"></form>
        </div>
    </body></html>
```

I already tried setting `preserveWhiteSpace` and `formatOutput` but that doesn't change anything.

It's not a big deal at all but it'd be nice if the output would look like the input.

Any ideas how to fix this?

And another question: is there a way to manually insert a `\n` linebreak after I added another node with `appendChild()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to reformat a document with DOM is

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("test.html");
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
$dom->saveHTMLFile("templates/test_neu.html");
```

If that doesnt result in the desired output, you can still add whitespace yourself. Any Whitespace used for formatting purposes is a `DOMText` Node. See my answers

- [DOMDocument in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979836/noob-question-about-domdocument-in-php/4983721#4983721) and
- [Printing content of a XML file using XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598409/printing-content-of-a-xml-file-using-xml-dom/4599724#4599724)

for a more detailed explanation. An alternative to that would be to use [Tidy](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) to reformat the code or any of the tools suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+beautifier+php

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried those two options but the formatting stays the same. I will have a look at your provides links. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question whilst looking for a solution to indent XSLTProcessor output. Here is an ungraceful alternative approach that might save somebody some time :

```
$xml -> preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml -> formatOutput = true;

$html = $xml -> saveXML();
$html = strstr( $html, '<html' );

file_put_contents( 'output.html', $html );
```

Any other configuration didn't work, for me in any case.