# PHP DOMDocument get children's tag name and value with childNodes

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, nodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing content of a XML file using XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598409/printing-content-of-a-xml-file-using-xml-dom)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<colors>
    <apple>red</apple>
    <banana>yellow</banana>
    <grape>purple</grape>
</colors>
```

Since fruit names (tag names) are **unknown**, I'm trying to get all tag names and values with `childNodes` of `<colors>`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("colors.xml");
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$root = $dom->getElementsByTagName("colors")->item(0);
$colors = $root->childNodes;

echo "<p>".$colors->length."</p>";

foreach($colors as $color) {
    echo "<p>".$color->nodeName." - ".$color->nodeValue."</p>";
}
```

`$colors->length` returns 7 instead of 3, and the result:

```
#text - 
apple - red
#text - 
banana - yellow
#text - 
grape - purple
#text -
```

Can someone please explain what are those `#text -`? And what's wrong with my code? Thanks.

## update

If I manually remove tabs and returns from the xml file, make the whole file into **one line**, `#text -` are gone. But I don't think that's the way it should be.

Comment: OK, thanks Gordon. My `$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;` goes after $dom->load where it should be before...

Comment: you're welcome and yupp, has to be before.